# Issue reading output from python process spawned by nodejs

Tags: python, node.js, unicode, child-process

I've been having an issue with character encoding when reading output from a spawned python process in node.

Here is the code for starting the spawned process, results is a JSON object.

```
const python = spawn('python', ['pvm.py'])
python.stdin.write(JSON.stringify(results));
python.stdin.end();
```

And the callback when the spawned process prints data

```
python.stdout.on('data', async function (result) {
    let pvm = result.toString()
    //other stuff
}
```

The python file simply prints a dictionary which has keys and values of characters generated by processing the JSON from stdin. When running the python file directly I receive 'ʊ': [2, []] as part of the output. The buffer in spawned process when converted to a string has 'ʊ': [1, ['�', '�']] instead, which I believe is being caused by an error putting the printed python text through the buffer.

Does anyone have any suggestions of why this is happening and how it can be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Anyone running into this issue in the future if using += to add a special character to a list use append instead.